# regex for dates

Tags: c#, regex

- Montag 28.03.2011
- Mi, 23.03.11
- 21.03.2011 - 27.03.2011

How can I get with REGEX 28.03.2011, 23.03.11 and 21.03.2011?

Last one I can get with split and " -", but how about first two? Can I somehow read just numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For that kind of problems I use Expresso - free and .NET compatible. (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm)

\d{2}[.]\d{2}[.]\d{4} - simplest pattern without value check

You may also tell us more what you are actually trying to do :)

For numbers extraction:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("(?<day>\d{2})[.](?<month>\d{2})\[.](?<year>(\d{4}|\d{2}))", RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);

Match match = regex.Match("20.03.2011");
if (match.Success)
{
   if (match.Groups["day"] != null)                           
   {
        string day = match.Groups["day"].value;
   }
   //etc.
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the individual dates with something like this:

```
(?<Day>\d{1,2})\.(?<Month>\d{1,2})\.(?<Year>(?:\d{4}|\d{2}))
```

I assume that's more useful than trying to strip out the 'Montag' and so on.